# MongoDB find function not returning the expected result

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, nosql

I m new to mongoDB, and I try to return a value from a search:

```
function verifyUser(username) {
var nrs = 0;
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if(err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("numbers");
    dbo.collection("numbers").find({ name: username }).toArray(function(err, res){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(res.length);
        db.close();   
    })
});}

verifyUser("test");
```

I have one record with the name 'test';

But when I try to prove it is not working:

```
console.log(verifyUser("test") === 1);
```

I tried to return instead of console.log but it doesn't work.

Comment: Your code works fine; make sure there is a database called as "numbers" and also a collection with the same name and with a document with following property: `{ name: 'test' }`

Comment: When i try to: return res.length, and after that console.log(verifyUser("test") === 1);, it gives me undefined

Comment: The function `verifyUser` should return a value to compare.

Comment: it's not: compiler test: false
1, when i return res.length only false

Comment: When the function `verifyUser` returns a value (i.e., the `res.length`) that value will be compared in the `console.log(verifyUser("test") === 1)`. So, modify your function to have that return statement.